# Tkinter: Show text of second tile before flipping back over in Memory game

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, time

I have created a memory game in python using tkinter, importing pairs of words from a file and shuffling them in a list. In the GUI, when I guess a tile for the second time, I want the tile that I clicked to reveal it's word for a *certain amount of time*, then flip back over again (if incorrect).

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
class Memory():
    """GUI for the game"""
    def __init__(self): 

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("Memory")
        self.number_unique_words = 8
        self.placement_index = 0
        self.counter = 0
        self.words = create_word_list(self.number_unique_words) #creates a list with pairs 
                                                                #of words
        self.answers = []
        self.buttons = []

        for row in range(4):
            for column in range(4):
                self.button = Button(self.root, text="", height=7, width=12, font=("DIN Alternate", 15))
                self.button.configure(command=lambda button=self.button, placement=self.placement_index: self.press_button(button, placement))
                self.button.grid(row=row, column=column)
                self.placement_index += 1

#My problem occurs here

    def press_button(self, button, placement):
        if button["text"] == "" and self.counter < 2:
            button["text"] = self.words[placement]
            self.answers.append(button["text"])
            self.buttons.append(button)
            self.counter += 1
        if len(self.answers) == 2:
            if self.answers[0] == self.answers[1]:
                for button in self.buttons:
                    button.configure(state="disabled")
                self.counter = 0
                self.answers = []
            else:
                for button in self.buttons:
                    button.configure(text="")
                self.counter = 0
                self.answers = []
                self.buttons = []
```

It works like I want it to, however when I guess the second tile, it "flips" both tiles instantly;  I never get to see the word of the second tile. I want to add some sort of delay, so that

```
button.configure(text="")
```

executes after a certain amount of time.

I have tried using `sleep`, although it never shows the word of the tile either, it just freezes the actual "click" of the button to what value I set. I have read about the `after` method but I never understood how to implement it.

Comment: Sounds like `tkinter.after()` is what you're looking for. It will call a given callback function *after* a given number of milliseconds. For example, you could define a function called `hide_tile` that configures your `Button` (tile) as you like, and then add `self.root.after(3000, hide_tile)` to call it after 3 seconds.

Comment: If the *certain amount of time* is within second, I don't mind using `sleep()` but you need to call `self.root.update()` to force tkinter to update before calling `sleep()`.